# React.js Render

Tags: reactjs

Доброго времени суток, экспериментирую с React.js

```
    class ButtonCreate extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.isLoad == "true") {
            $(this.refs.toggleInput).tooltip({ container: 'body' });
        }     
    }

    render() {
        return <button type="button" ref="toggleInput" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-create" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Создать новый элемент">Создать</button>;
    }
}
    class ButtonDelete extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: props.element };
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick(e) {
        if (this.props.isLoad == "true") {
            $(this.refs.toggleInput).tooltip('hide');
        }
        this.props.onRemove(false);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.isLoad == "true") {
            $(this.refs.toggleInput).tooltip({ container: 'body' });
        }
    }

    buttonCaption() {
        if (this.props.isCancel) {
            return "Отменить";
        } else {
            return "Удалить";
        }
    }

    buttonTooggle() {
        if (this.props.isCancel) {
            return "Отменить удаление";
        } else {
            return "Установить пометку удаления";
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <button type="button" ref="toggleInput" className="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-delete" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover click" data-toggle="tooltip" title={this.buttonTooggle()} onClick={this.onClick}>{this.buttonCaption()}</button>;
    }
}


class Company extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: props.company };
        this.onDeleteElement = this.onDeleteElement.bind(this);
    }

    stateElement() {
        if (this.state.data.markDelete) {
            return "1";
        } else {
            return "0";
        }
    }

    onDeleteElement(isDel) {
        this.props.onRemove(this.state.data, isDel);
    }

    render() {
        var remove = this.onDeleteElement; 
        return <tr>
            <td>{this.stateElement()}</td>
            <td>{this.state.data.code}</td>
            <td>{this.state.data.name}</td>
            <td><ButtonDelete isLoad="true" isCancel={this.state.data.markDelete} element={this.state.data} onRemove={remove} /></td>
        </tr>;
    }
}

class CompanyList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { companys: [] };
        this.onDeleteElement = this.onDeleteElement.bind(this);
    }

    loadData() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("get", this.props.apiUrl, true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            this.setState({ companys: data });
            this.render();
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.send();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData();
    }

    onDeleteElement(element, isDel) {
        if (element) {

            var data = JSON.stringify({ "ref": element.ref });
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = this.props.apiUrl + "/" + isDel;

            xhr.open("delete", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    this.loadData();
                }
            }.bind(this);
            xhr.send(data);
        }
    }

    render() {
        var remove = this.onDeleteElement;
        return <div>
            <ButtonCreate isLoad="fasle" />
            <div className="well well-sm main-well">
                <table className="table table-hover cursor-pointer list-vertical">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th className="list-markdelete"></th>
                            <th>Код</th>
                            <th>Наименование</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.companys.map(function (company) {
                                return <Company key={company.ref} company={company} onRemove={remove} />
                            })
                        }

                    </tbody>
                </table></div></div>;
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <CompanyList apiUrl="/api/Company" />,
    document.getElementById("CompanyList")
);
```

В компоненте CompanyList после срабатывания удаления (onDeleteElement) в метод LoadData приходит новый измененный объект (markDelete изменилась, проверял в отладчике), но CompanyList  не перерисовывается, он остается прежним, то есть рендер не произошел. Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка, уже все перепробовал. Перерисовывается только после перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 0):

> `<ButtonCreate isLoad="fasle" />`

Попробуй поставить False )

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Рендер не происходил потому, что изменение свойств объекта в  массиве (companys: []), не является признаком изменения всего массива. Признаком изменения массива является изменение количества элементов.